# To apply changes done to "/etc/my.cnf", do we need to restart mysqld service?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I need to change `max_connections` parameter in `/etc/my.cnf`. After doing the change, do we need to restart mysqld service to apply the changes?
I'm on CentOS 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some server parameters are dynamic and can be changed on the fly. Some are not and should be configured in the `my.cnf` followed by service restart. `max_connections` can be changed on the fly by command `SET GLOBAL max_connections=XXX`. This value will be in effect until service restart.

---

To be clear, the possible options are:

- Run `SET GLOBAL max_connections = XXX` for immediate use until service restarted
- Add the `max_connections = XXX` line to the `[mysqld]` section of the `my.cnf` **AND** restart the service for permanent use
- Run `SET GLOBAL max_connections = XXX` **AND** add the `max_connections = XXX` line to the `my.cnf` but **DO NOT** restart the service.

The third option allows to get both immediate changes as well as permanent but with zero downtime. Value in the `my.cnf` will wait for some event/incident/accident causing a service's restart.

Comment: To make the ``` max_connections ``` parameter change permanent, we need to restart the service, right?

Comment: @PradeepSanjeewa Right. Placed in `my.cnf` this value becomes permanent, but you do not need to restart the serveice immediately. You can set it dynamically for immediate use and change it in the `my.cnf` where it will postponed until restart.

Comment: And MySQL 8.0 has a `SET PERSIST ...`